# Tell me I can't award the bounty before the warning:

Tags: feature-request, bounties, warning

This

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

appears before this

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Please can the order be changed, so I don't get the popup before the notice.

Comment: Yeah I hate little frustrations like that. Lets me start doing something, then half way through tell me I cannot  and everything before that was pointless. (Or leave it as is and the red box says "What are you trying to do, Dave")

Comment: I'm trying to think of other things like this but can't right now... I'm sure there are some. It's only when there are like 2+ steps in it.

Comment: I've come across other things similar around the site. They seem too trivial to report, tho I probs should

Comment: Even better: have the "+[x]" grayed out, with a tooltip containing that message. No need to allow us to click in the first place, same way like we see grayed out (disabled) "edit" when edit is not possible.

Comment: @Mooseman I find it *logical* from dev perspective. I find it *frustrating* from a user perspective.

Comment: @Mooseman Sites should be to cater for users, and it's not *user-friendly* to say "Here, do this" and when I start to do so I'm then told "No, you can't do that". . "Jim, this is a most illogical decision, I must protest"

Comment: @Sha that would work even better!